# Serialize class with object field as boolean

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have the following class :

```
public class Variable
{
    // lower case to generate JSON we need

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public object ValueInfo { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"[Name={Name}, [Type={Type}, Value={Value}, ValueInfo={ValueInfo}";
}
```

And I'm filling this class with multiples dataTypes for the field "Value" in specific i having problem when is a boolean value.

```
var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
```

the result after serialize is :

```json
{"correcto":{"Name":null,"Type":null,"Value":"true","ValueInfo":null}
```

And I need in the field "Value" as boolean true not "true".

Is there a way to keep the boolean value?

Comment: What do you store in `Value` before you serialise it? Can you share some code of how you're using `Variable`?

Comment: "I'm filling this class with multiples dataTypes for the field "Value" in specific i having problem when is a boolean value." I'm seeing some red flags here. `"true"` is _not_ a boolean value: it's a string. If the JSON is supposed to represent a boolean value there, it should use `true` (without quotes) instead. Otherwise, how are you supposed to differentiate between an intended boolean value and an intended string value which just happens to have the text "true" in it?

Comment: Can't reproduce, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/8sDGPR.  If I create `request` as follows: `var request = new { correcto = new Variable { Value = true } };` and serialize the result, I get `{"correcto":{"Name":null,"Type":null,"Value":true,"ValueInfo":null}}`.  Notice that `Value` has bee serialized as a Boolean **not** as a string.  Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

try to add a custom setter to your class

```
public class Variable
{
    // lower case to generate JSON we need

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    private object _value;
    public object Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (value as string == "true") _value = true;
            else
              if (value as string == "false") _value = false;
            else _value = value;
        }
    }

    public object ValueInfo { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"[Name={Name}, [Type={Type}, Value={Value}, ValueInfo={ValueInfo}";
}
```

another way, if you only need this for a serialization, you can add a Json constructor instead of changing a setter

```
     public Variable() {}

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Variable(object Value)
    {
        if (Value as string == "true") this.Value = true;
        else
              if (Value as string == "false") this.Value = false;
        else this.Value = Value;
    }
```

test

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Variable { Value = "true"});

// result

{"Name":null,"Type":null,"Value":true,"ValueInfo":null}
```

Comment: Please correct in the else for false, to assign to false , this answer works!

Comment: @IvanFontalvo it was just a typo , i fixed it